# Cannot set up Microsoft Custom Translate on Memsource

Tags: microsoft-translator, bing-translator-api

I am trying to set up Microsoft Custom Translate on Memsource based on [these instructions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/trial/#get-started):

I get a message saying the category parameter is invalid. What should I set the parameter as?

Comment: I found that "general" worked.

Comment: general will not use your custom translator model, but instead use the generic one, same as on bing translator, for example. The category is listed in your project at the top. It is called 'category id'.